# (firebaseError code: -5) "The active or pending auth credentials were superseded by another call to auth"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to login from another test device with no changes in the code. I'm 200% sure that I'm using a correct credentials and token. I just don't understand why I encounter it during authentication.

**Details**

> "The active or pending auth credentials were superseded by another
>   call to auth"

**Code:**

> -5

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you share the minimal code that triggers the behavior. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve